# steps to install sql2008 and have it accessible via SSMS remotely tied to a IPaddress

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-firewall

How hard is it to install sql2008 on a server, and giving access to me from my home computer via Management Studio?

Can I lock this down to a particular IP address?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more secure to set up a VPN connection to the network where the SQL server is located and access it via the VPN connection.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with joeqwerty, but for the sake of answering your question itself it's not hard.  You install SQL Server normally then configure your firewall to allow inbound connections to your server on the port your instance is listening (default is TCP 1433).  You use the firewall to lock it down to a specific IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Not hard at all?
I would change the default port from 1433 to something else, in case  [Slammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_slammer_%28computer_worm%29) ever happens again.

The built-in windows firewall on windows server 2003 allows you to restrict an incoming service to a particular IP/network. See the example screen shot below.  Don't forget to include your local network in the list. Nonetheless, I would still feel more comfortable putting an enterprise firewall in front of my server if i was putting it out on the internet.

[image]